# Checking for user role in a custom plugin

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, user-roles

In my theme's `functions.php` file I have no trouble checking for user role. I've checked in two different ways:

```
if ( current_user_can('wholesale_customer') ) { 
    // my code
}
```

and

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'wholesale_customer', (array) $current_user->roles )) {
// my code
}
```

Both of these work flawlessly in my `functions.php` file. However, I have a custom plugin, and simply putting in the:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

part makes the entire page not work. So my question is: how do I check current user in a custom plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Why it doesn't work for a Plugin:

It doesn't work for plugin because by the time WordPress executes `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();` in a plugin, the function `wp_get_current_user()` isn't defined yet. WordPress loads that plugin file before it defines those user related functions. However, it works for theme because WordPress loads theme after it defines and initiates those user centric functions.

## How to make it work in a plugin:

For it to work in a plugin, you may use an action hook. For example, it'll work after `plugins_loaded` action hook is fired. Like the CODE below:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'check_current_user' );
function check_current_user() {
    // Your CODE with user data
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    
    // Your CODE with user capability check
    if ( current_user_can('wholesale_customer') ) { 
        // Your CODE
    }
}
```

With the above CODE you'll see checking role with `current_user_can()` and getting user information with `wp_get_current_user()` works inside a plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I figured it was something like that, I didn't know about that action hook though, that will come in handy down the line! It works flawlessly now :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you :). BTW, you may study about WordPress filter and action hook loading order. That will do real wonders for you down the line. You may start with this post: http://rachievee.com/the-wordpress-hooks-firing-sequence/

Comment: Thank you, I will definitively check it out! The more I can learn the better :)